# Retrieve database in java using JTextField to search

Tags: java, sql

So, i would like to retrieve database information where a user will search certain columns using text fields, like this:

column1 find userinput,
column2 find userinput,
column3 find userinput,

The problem im having is the sql statement:

```
String sql = "select * from table where column = '" + textfield1.getText() + "'";
```

If textfield1 is empty, it will only retrieve entries that contain nothing.

What im trying to retrieve will have 6 text field, meaning 6 columns in the database. Using java i would need alot of **if statements**.

Is there any other way to shorten this?

EDIT
-- MORE INFO --

The if statements will start from:

```
if (!(t1.getText().equals("")) && !(t2.getText().equals("")) && !(t3.getText().equals(""))
&& !(t4.getText().equals("")) && !(t5.getText().equals("")) && (t6.getText().equals("")))
```

all the way down to

```
if (t1.getText().equals("") && t2.getText().equals("") && t3.getText().equals("")
&& t4.getText().equals("") && t5.getText().equals("") && t6.getText().equals("")
```

covering all possible combinations of the 6 input fields, the point of all these statements is to ignore empty text fields but provide the corresponding sql statement.

I don't know how to calculate the possible combinations other than writing them all down(i started, there was too many).

Comment: What's supposed to happen if two JTextView's are not empty?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want, pls elaborate or provide some more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really understand why those `ifs`, you should elaborate more your question but i will try to help as i can.

Well, if you want to retrieve everything from the database you could use LIKE:

```
String sql = "select * from table where column like '%" + textfield1.getText() + "%'";
```

This way you'll get everything with the containing text, it means, if the field is `empty` it will bring all results, i guess this is the best way to do, to avoid unnecessa `if` clauses.

Another thing, to check for empty fields you should use:

```
t1.getText().trim().isEmpty()
```

BUT if you let they write white spaces the `LIKE` won't help you then you need to .trim() all your texts then your white spaces will be ignored.

Comment: The like operator will work fine, thank you for reminding me it existed haha.

Comment: Thanks :) we're here to help, it's good to know that it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

The following can be formulated much neater, but to make the point:

```
JTextField ts = new JTextField[6];

Set<String> values = new HashSet<>(); // Removes duplicates too.
for (JTextField t : ts) {
    String text = ts.getText().trim();
    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
        values.add(text);
    }
}

// Build the WHERE condition of a PreparedStatement
String condition = "";
for (String value : values) {
    condition += condition.isEmpty() ? "WHERE" : " OR";
    condition += " column = ?";
}

String sql = "select * from table " + condition;
PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
int index = 1; // SQL counts from 1
for (String value : values) {
    stm.setString(index, value);
    ++index;
}
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
```

The usage of a PreparedStatement makes escaping `'` (and backslash and such) no longer needed and also prevents SQL injection (see wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

i have a problem i want to search data based on multiple jtext fields where did i go wrong coz this displays only one row which has the first id

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sql="SELECT Employee.EmpID,Employee.Fname,Employee.Mname,Employee.Sname,Employee.DoB,Employee.Phone,"
                    + "Employee.Email,Employee.Nationality,Employee.Desegnition,Employee.NSSF,Employee.WCF,"
                    + "Employee.BSalary,Allowance.medical,Allowance.Bonus,Allowance.others,Allowance.tov,Allowance.TA,"
                    + "Attendece.Hrs from Employee,Allowance,Attendece WHERE "
                    + "Employee.EmpID=Allowance.EmpID and Attendece.EmpID=Allowance.EmpID AND Employee.EmpID=? AND Attendece.Dt=?";
     try{



             pd=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
             pd.setString(1,id.getText());
             pd.setString(2,Date1.getText());
             r=pd.executeQuery();



             //setting the text fields
        if(r.next())
        {
        String a=r.getString("EmpID");
        eid.setText(a);
        String b=r.getString("Fname");
        fname.setText(b);
        String c=r.getString("Mname");
        mname.setText(c);
        String d=r.getString("Sname");
        sname.setText(d);
        String e=r.getString("DoB");
        dob.setText(e);
        String f=r.getString("Desegnition");
        Des.setText(f);
         String g=r.getString("Bsalary");
        bsal.setText(g);
          String h=r.getString("Phone");
       phone.setText(h);
          String i=r.getString("Email");
        email.setText(i);
          String j=r.getString("Nationality");
        nationality.setText(j);
          String k=r.getString("Desegnition");
        Des.setText(k);
          String l=r.getString("NSSf");
        nssf.setText(l);
          String m=r.getString("WCF");
        wcf.setText(m);
         String n=r.getString("tov");
        oh.setText(n);
         String o=r.getString("Bonus");
        bn.setText(o);
         String p=r.getString("medical");
        md.setText(p);
         String q=r.getString("others");
        ot.setText(q);
         String s=r.getString("TA");
        ta.setText(s);
         String t=r.getString("Hrs");
        hrs.setText(t);

        int day;
        day=Integer.parseInt(t)/8;
        days.setText(Integer.toString(day));

        double week=day/7;
        weeks.setText(Double.toString(week));

        }
        r.close();
        pd.close();



    }catch(Exception e)
    {



    }
```

Comment: Why are you posting your Question as an Answer? It will be very much harder for people to find your posting (and provide useful feedback) than creating a new Question.